# How can I make Flash fullscreen on an external display?

Tags: adobe-flash

The question is: I have a laptop, and I extend my desktop on external display, so I get a wide desktop (3200px). When I make the videos on flash fullscreen, don't know why, but the fullscreen appears on my little part of desktop (the laptop display).

Is there any way to tell flash to play fullscreen on my bigger part?

Answer (score 1):

Flash will enter full screen mode on your primary display. In the configuration for your dual monitor set up there should be the option to set the external as the primary display.

Comment: well, it should, but it doesn't =) Tried to switch primary screen in nvidia-settings, but anyway fullscreen appears on the laptop

Answer (score 1):

You can change your primary display temporarily with xrandr. I.e. open a terminal and run:

`xrandr --output HDMI1 --primary`

Where HDMI1 is the RandR output name for your external display. You can determine the name by listing all the outputs with `xrandr -q`. E.g. in my case, my notebook screen is `DP1` and my external LCD (hooked up via DVI) is `HDMI1`.

Note: If this messes up the relative position of your monitors, you can fix it with something like:

`xrandr --output HDMI1 --auto --pos 0x0 --output DP1 --auto --right-of HDMI1`

This puts my notebook screen to the right of my external monitor. If your notebook is to the left of your external monitor, change `--right-of` to `--left-of`.

To make it permanent, you can run xrandr from a script and stick it somewhere that gets launched automatically (e.g. Startup Applications on Ubuntu).