# How to fix flash fullscreen from appearing on the side of the screen

Tags: kde, adobe-flash, xrandr

My situation is similar to the one described in [How can I make flash fullscreen on an external display](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6024/how-can-i-make-flash-fullscreen-on-an-external-display). I also have a laptop extended with a larger screen. Aside from KDE wildly resetting the screens relative positions (the xrandr's `--left-of`) every time I reboot (curiously enough, it remembers which screen is the main one), which I managed to override with putting small xrandr's command in `.xsession`, I have a bigger problem. Whenever I want some flash app to go fullscreen, it appears on the right side of the current screen (i.e. the one on which I clicked some flash fullscreen button). Always the right side, no matter which screen is *left of* the other one. The other side of the screen is black and also the other screen is unaffected in any way.

I would think it's just flash but fullscreen worked perfectly on the same setting with XFCE. Is there any known solution to this situation?